# Ramification indices and residue class degrees of $\mathfrak{O}_K$ where $K=Q[\alpha]$, $f(\alpha)=0$, and $f(x)=x^3-x-1$.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, dedekind-domain, ramification

I already know that $\alpha^3-\alpha-1=0$ implies that $\{1,\alpha, \alpha^2 \}$ creates an integral basis for $\mathbb{A} \cap \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$. I'd like to try to use Dedekind's theorem in some fashion to find the ramification indices and residue class degrees of the prime ideals of $\mathfrak{O}_K$ which lie above 2, 5, and 23.

I'm not sure if it would be an entirely separate problem for each of the primes, but any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: $x^3-x-1$ is irreducible modulo $p=2$, factors as a product of a linear and an irreducible quadratic modulo $p=5$, factors completely modulo $p=23$ *with a repeated factor*.

Comment: Compare with what you know about the splitting of primes in quadratic fields. $x^2+1$ factors as $(x-2)(x+2)$ modulo $p=5$, stays irreducible modulo $p=3$ and has a repeated factor modulo $p=2$. To see why we need a monomial integral basis compare that case with $x^2+9$. The same splitting field, but this one has a repeated factor modulo $p=3$.

Comment: Also, it now seems City is going to take the Premier League

Comment: and the cubic factors completely $\mod p$ for every prime $p=u^2 +uv + 6 v^2 $ (well, other than 23) and is irreducible $\mod q$ for every prime $q=2m^2 +mn + 3 n^2$ bigger than $2$